# Drupal multiple features and unreusable components

Tags: drupal, components

This is a general question on how Features should be created when we have components that could potentially be used in multiple features.

Suppose a context (c1) takes a view (v1) and is added to a feature (f1).  Now let's say v1 has potential use somewhere else and i want to create a new feature (f2) to include it in...but the Features module doesn't give you the option to do so.  The only thing i can do is cloning v1 into v2 and use that in f2.

I may be shortsighted, but I think that if f2 needed v1, then just add the other components that would make up f2 and put them in f1...because more likely than not, those two features would be closely related (see [One big feature...](http://drupal.org/node/928946)), at least enough to warrant using the same view (which in turn could include the same node types, roles, etc...)

I guess i'm just curious, has there been a case where you've created a feature with a view, and then needed to have a different feature using that same view?

Comment: Is there a reason that f2 can't depend on f1?

Comment: Not sure if i understand your question, but features are mutually exclusive....if a feature depended on another one, then i think it would to be part of it.

Comment: Maybe you could ask moderators to migrate your interesting Drupal question to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution in your case is to add a dependency from f2 to f1 to make sure that you have your v1 available.
You can't add v1 in f2 a second because your view would be defined twice and features would create a circular dependency.

Otherwise, to create reusable components, you should clone your view to make sure that you have "everything" you need in one same feature.

Comment: Yea, cloning would be the way to go in my case.  I ran into another conflict when i wanted to have permissions set for new roles created for a feature.  Turned out that "access administer menu", for example, was already used in a different feature...Cloning would not help there unfortunately.

Comment: @nymo if a permission is already exported in an other feature, it shouldn't appear on the strongarm variables.
Every roles are defined in the same permission.

Comment: The perms were not in the strongarm variables list, but in the permissions' one.

Comment: My bad, you are right. Strongarm is about all the variables of the settings forms.